# Does jQuery do some magic with the `this` variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery has gotten us used to the following `this` pattern:

```
$(selector).each(function () {
     // do something with `this`
     // `this` iterates over the DOM elements inside `$(selector)`
});
```

According to [this Crockford talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM) (about 15 minutes in) the value of `this` inside a function that is not called with the `new` operator is the global object, except for ES5 strict mode in which case it is `undefined`.

Does jQuery do some magic with `this` to get it to something other than the global object? Please point to specific lines of the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just regular javascript with  [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and
[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Relevant part from jQuery source:

```
if ( isObj ) {
    for ( name in object ) {
        if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    for ( ; i < length; ) {
        if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`callback` refers to your function which is called with `.call`.:

```
function asd(){
     alert( this.i ); // 3
}

asd.call( {i: 3} );
```

Comment: @Raynos - Excuse me, I didn't change those functions. I know what the edit *says*, but **I'm not stupid**.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, you put the wrong part of source code which I initially had and removed the thing that said it's from jQuery source. All for nothing but function indendation and linking style. :P

Comment: @Raynos - This is what happened: Esailija posted a Google link. I edited to point the *Google* link and to format the code (which is *all* I did). *Esailija* then edited the answer and it somehow shows that I made a bunch of changes, which **did not happen**. Note how the Google link disappeared from the edit history.

Comment: I did not. SO got confused with the edit somehow (I assume it has something to do with how the edits can be made but not recorded).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I was rapidly editing my post in order to compete with the non-answer getting upvotes so quickly. Something you must do here at SO :(

Comment: Note, if you look at the history, you *won't* see the tab-delimited code you posted, or the Google link. I don't know how it got screwed up, but I made **lightweight** edits only.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, but that *one* edit was not meant to be a big deal. And I saw you edit it just fine right after that.

Comment: fair enough, then it's probably the edit history breaking at the 5 minute barrier. Might want to mark this as a bug on meta.SO

Comment: @JaredFarrish, there is some problems with SO caching/solar flares etc. What you see is not what others see always, it's best to leave posts alone when they are fresh and the question is new as it's a very common strategy to get a quick post out and start rapidly editing it.

Comment: SO has mechanisms that usually handle that case; this has never happened to me before, on either end. I know how to handle questions and answers, thank you.

Comment: @JaredFarrish for future reference try not to take it so personally and get so defensive. It has a negative effect on our interpretation of your character.

Comment: @Raynos - For future reference, don't curse at people. Ditto. `;)`

Comment: Bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116404/bug-in-edit-history-associated-with-initial-answer-phase-non-recorded

Comment: @JaredFarrish hear hear. I'll be less aggressive.

Comment: @Raynos - I was worked up, I won't deny it (but not as much as it probably came across). I thought, briefly, that nobody would believe me when I saw that edit log (after the initial *what are you talking about*). Once I started figuring it out, I felt more comfortable I could communicate it was a mistake. My takeaway from this whole escapade is that I will certainly be more caution (that I already am) about editing answers.

Comment: @JaredFarrish you did nothing. Stackoverflow screwed up. i accused you of screwing the answer up, you rightfully defended yourself. Then we wasted time bickering rather then complaining on meta.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery uses the 100% non-magical [`Function.call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the callback with a specific `this`.

Comment: [`callback.call( object[ i ] , ...`](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7/jQuery.each#L660) where `object[ i ]` is the i-th DOM element in the jQuery selection

Answer (score 7):

Trimmed and rephrased from [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L606) to match your usage:

```
jQuery.each = jQuery.fn.each = function( object, callback ) {

    for ( var i = 0, length = object.length ; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i ] ) === false ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return object;
};
```

This is the important part: `callback.call`.

It is time, my son, for you to meet the `this` value. `this` has a name which pinpoints exactly what it refers to - the container. `this` has several possible values.

**Note**: Because of its name, `this` is a difficult value to talk about. So whenever in a code comment or code explanation you see the word `self` (working name), it refers to the `this` value.

```
var o = {
    log : function () {
        console.log( this );
    }
};
o.log(); //will log the object o

function log () {
    console.log( this );
}
//the default enclosing object is the global object - window
//this is the behaviour you observed in Crockford's talk
log();

//the self value is not set in stone. it is evaluated when the function is called
var grass = {
    log : o.log,
    color : 'purple'
};
grass.log(); //will log the object grass
//this is different from languages where self is static. in such languages, doing
// grass.log() would've logged the original object, o, but since self is evaluated
// at runtime, it is set to the now containing object - grass
```

A phenomena we see in everyday life is mutating `self`. When I see a Mudkip and yell out "this is blue!", I do not refer to myself, despite my blueish tones. Instead, I announced who the new value of `this` will be (by pointing at it.) Such a thing can be done in js, and that is what happens in `jQuery.each`.

It's time to meet `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`. Their behavior is best observed by an example:

```
grass.speak = function ( message ) {
    //a philosophical conundrum: how does grass talk?
    console.log( this.color + ' ' + message );
};
grass.speak( ' fruit' ); //will log "blue fruit"

var ultraGrass = {
    color : 'maroon'
};

grass.speak.call( ultraGrass, ', hijacked!' ); //will log "maroon, hijacked!"
```

`Function.prototype.call` (I'll just call it `call` from now. get it? call it...call...nevermind) accepts two parameters: A `thisArg` and a variable-length parameter list.

`call` and `apply` invoke a function with a specified `self` value (the first parameter) and a parameter list (the rest of the parameters in `call`'s case, the second parameter in `apply`'s case.)

```
Function.prototype.call( thisArg, arg0, arg1, arg2, ... );
Function.prototype.apply( thisArg, [arg0, arg1, arg2, ...] );
```

Following a more traditional example:

```
function average () {
    console.log( this ); //to see what call and apply actually do

    for ( var i = 0, sum = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        sum += arguments[ i ];
    }
    return sum / ( len || 1 ); //don't want to divide by zero!
}

average( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ); //will log the global object, and return 3

average.call( grass, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ); //will log the grass object, and return 3
average.apply( grass, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ); //will do the same as above

log.call( ultraGrass ); //will log ultraGrass
log.apply( ultraGrass ); //will also log ultraGrass
```

The only difference between `call` and `apply` is that apply expects an array of arguments, and call uses everything passed to it after the first parameter as arguments.

Returning to the original jQuery code:

```
callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i ] )
```

It invokes the `callback` function with:

1. The `this` value set to `object[ i ]`, and
2. Two parameters: `i` and `object[ i ]`

For more information:

1. [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on MDN
2. [apply](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.3) and [call](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4) in the ES5 spec